# Mention tagging gets mistaken for action tagging

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

While trying to submit an OpenGraph action to Facebook, the feedback we receive states that we should use mention tagging instead of action tagging:

> The Action Tagging additional property can only be used when the tagged user is also performing the real action. Otherwise use the Mention Tagging additional property to include another user in the story.

But in our instructions on how to reproduce the action, we clearly state we implement "mention tagging", and as far as I can tell, the app complies with [the requirements](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/action-properties/#mentiontagging) as listed in the documentation.

What could cause FB to believe we use action tagging instead of mention tagging?
Is there a way to receive more specific information on the failed submission?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was a pain in the backside for weeks as I kept resubmitting my open graph action for approval and it was continually rejected.  My solution was to:

a) update the description to ensure that I made it clear that the app was using mention tagging rather than action tagging.

b) I used a timeline screenshot that clearly showed the words "FB friend" was mentioned in your profile (where "FB friend" is the name of the friend you have chosen for the mention tag).

As Facebook doesn't actually review and approve the iOS app, its reviewers can only go on the description and screenshots you provide. So, if it's not getting through, you need to make it absolutely clear in idiot-proof steps, exactly what your app does. If you continue to get rejections, ask the reviewers for help within the submission text - sometimes that gets a better response that will help direct you!